# Ubuntu на сервере перешла в состояние Read-only file system. Как исправить без перезагрузки?

Tags: ubuntu

На сервере `Linux ubuntusrv 2.6.32-45-server`, сегодня в один прекрасный момент система начала себя очень странно вести - перешла в режим `Read-only file system`. Подумал, что bad-блоки на диске и дал команду `sudo fsck -Af`

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
/dev/mapper/ubuntusrv-root: recovering journal
Clearing orphaned inode 5117251 (uid=1001, gid=1001, mode=040755, size=4096)
...
Clearing orphaned inode 5116637 (uid=1001, gid=1001, mode=0100644, size=860291)
Clearing orphaned inode 3024748 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100644, size=769)
Clearing orphaned inode 5642465 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=060000, size=0)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/mapper/ubuntusrv-root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntusrv-root: ***** REBOOT LINUX *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntusrv-root: 637500/6356992 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 7048072/25397248 blocks
```

Систему перезагружать нельзя потому что `uptime`. Суть проблемы в том что при любой попытке изменить ФС, выдается сообщение `Read-only file system`, например:

```
# touch test
touch: cannot touch `test': Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /dev/mapper/ubuntusrv-root
```